# How to add tabhost control on each page of our android application?

Tags: android

I want to display and handle events of tabhost control on each page of android application without creating it again and again, as in asp.net we have masterpage concept on which we can place our common controls, is there anything in android, so that i can place tabcontrol there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should extend you Activity with TabActivity and also use TabHost and TabSpec 
one example for xml is

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <TabHost android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost">
   <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
 <TabWidget     android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        </TabWidget>
<FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>

  </TabHost>
```

Comment: I know that we can extend tabactivity, i had created tabhost but i don't want to create tab again and again for every page, if i extend tabactivity on every page of my application this means i create new tab control for every page but, i want to just create it once & use it on every page as master page concept in asp.net

Comment: Well you don't have to extend tabactivity for each activity rather create one activity which extends from TabActivity. Then when you use TabHost, remember that it keeps all the tabs. Then there is TabSpec which basically makes you able to set the content of each tabs. With the help of setIndicator() and setContent() names and content of each tabs.After all these you have to add these tabSpec to tabHost.TabSpec firstTabSpec =tabHost.newTabSpec("tabIndicator1");
firstTabSpec.setIndicator("First Tab").setContent(new Intent(this,FirstTab.class));
As you can see you just call another activity here

Comment: suppose i clicked on first tab it will open a page which contains a button & when i click on that button login page will open & now i want tabcontrol on that login page without recreating it.

Comment: so you want both your first Tab screen and the login page both under the same tab?

Comment: I have not tried this, but I think it will solve your problem
http://ericharlow.blogspot.com/2010/09/experience-multiple-android-activities.html

Comment: actually it works fine for static pages but when we maintain this with the pages calling web service(fetching data from asp.net web service) it's not working properly.

Comment: So you mean that if your screen goes dynamic then you see the problem. Have you tried to test with any other dynamic view. What I am understanding is that if is problem with dynamic view then you can try to inflate view and see if it works.

Comment: my view is not created dynamically but data on that view are fetched dynamically with help of web service.

Comment: In the solution provided by u how to again start activity which extends tabgroupactivity class, it is giving error when we r again coming back to the class which extends tabgroupactivity class & if we move to any other class then it works fine.

Comment: i am having 4 tabs which shares single page with dynamic data, i.e. the same page is used to display different data according to the tab is clicked and its child page also have similar sort of functionality. But sometimes in navigation application closed forcefully